# First and Last Day of 4 Weeks in C# DateTime Objects

Tags: c#, datetime, weekday

I'm trying to Get the First and Last Day of 4 Weeks based on the given Date.

**For Example:**

- If the given Date is `8-Jan-2023` then the week start and end should be `1-Jan-2023` and `28-Jan-2023` respectively.
- If the given Date is `10-Jan-2023` then the week start and end should be `1-Jan-2023` and `28-Jan-2023` respectively.
- If the given Date is `30-Jan-2023` then the week start and end should be `29-Jan-2023` and `25-Jan-2023` respectively.

Basically, the use case depends on the `very first input`. If the first input is 15-Jan then the first 4 weeks are recorded in the database as 15-Jan to 11-Feb. In that case, 17-Jan belongs to that week

How to do this?

I'm getting the Start Day & end Date of the week as below:

```
public static DateTime FirstDayOfWeek(this DateTime dt)
{
    var culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    var diff = dt.DayOfWeek - culture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;
    if (diff < 0)
    {
        diff += 7;
    }
    return dt.AddDays(-diff).Date;
 }

 public static DateTime LastDayOfFourWeeks(this DateTime dt) =>
            dt.FirstDayOfWeek().AddDays(27);
```

Comment: So many people provide examples for stuff like this but not the actual rules. You've provided three examples with no explanation of why things should be that way. Are you saying, without actually saying, that any date within the first four weeks of a month should return the four-week range starting at the beginning of that month and any other date should return the four-week range starting on the 29th of that month? If not, what are you saying? Explain the rules, not just a few cases that obey those rules.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Assuming 4 weeks is `8-Jan-2023` to `4-Feb-2023`. Any date within this range should return the start date of the week as `8-Jan-2023` and the end date of the week as `4-Feb-2023`. When I specify the input date as `5-Feb-2023` then it's a new 4 week range from `5-Feb-2023` to `4-Mar-2023`

Comment: @UnknownCoder: Why is the your weekrange from ```8-Jan``` to ```4-Feb```and not from ```15-Jan``` to ```11-Feb```.  The ```17-Jan``` could belong to both ranges.

Comment: @GWimpassinger basically, the use case depends on the `very first input`. If the first input is `15-Jan` then the first 4 weeks are recorded in the database as `15-Jan` to `11-Feb`. In that case, `17-Jan` belongs to that week.

Comment: @UnknownCoder: So the _very first input_ defines the 4 week periods. But you have not used it in your description or code example.